# No me aparece el progressbar en mi webview con ConstraintLayout

Tags: android-studio, webview

actualmente estoy usando una webview para un proyecto, he implementado el progressbar pero a la hora de emular la app y probarla en mi dispositivo fisico esta no sale, no se que hice mal :(

MainActivity

```
package com.vtelekom.mcs.zynga;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView browser;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Definimos el webView
        browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.homepage);

        //Habilitamos JavaScript
        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        //Habilitamos los botones de Zoom
        browser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);

        browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        // Cargamos la web
        browser.loadUrl("https://www.zynga.com/");

        //Sincronizamos la barra de progreso de la web
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

        browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                progressBar.setProgress(0);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                MainActivity.this.setProgress(progress * 1000);

                progressBar.incrementProgressBy(progress);

                if (progress == 100) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if (browser.canGoBack())
        {
            browser.goBack();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

activivity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

   <WebView
       android:id="@+id/homepage"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero debes sobreescribir el método `onPageStarted` y alli mostrar tu Progressbar, en el `onProgressChanged` sol debes ir aumentando tu progressbar

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView browser;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
        // Definimos el webView
        browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.homepage);
        //Habilitamos JavaScript
        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //Habilitamos los botones de Zoom
        browser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
        // Cargamos la web
        //Sincronizamos la barra de progreso de la web
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                if (progress == 100) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
        browser.loadUrl("https://www.zynga.com/");
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (browser.canGoBack()) {
            browser.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

En tu xml primero pon el webView y luego el progressbar

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/homepage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: ahora si me funciona, gracias, espero que tu respuesta ayude a mas personas que inician en la programacion ya que esto del progressbar en la webview es un problema comun aunque no lo parezca

Comment: Me alegra que te fiunciono! saludos